# CSS 3 selecting elements by checking an attribute for multiple values

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I want to apply the same style to text and email input types. 
I tried `input[type="text"][type="email"]` but it's not working. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try without " for example input[type=text]. If you want to apply it to both, try

```
input[type=text], input[type=email]
```

or

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"]
```

They're equivalent.

Comment: Quotes or not doesn't make a difference here (I downvoted both answers for the same reason)...

Comment: You should correct this answer if it is the accepted one. The solution is not the removeal of quotes, it is the seperation of the selectors - from `input[type="text"][type="email"]` to `input[type="text"], input[type="email"]`

Comment: @programer1234 - your solution only works because you have seperated the selectors - if you just remove the speech marks form the askers CSS selector - as your answer suggests - then your solution would not work: http://tinkerbin.com/8D72oFu4

Comment: Yeah, because first I misunderstood the question. Later I improved it. You're of course allright :)